# How to give AWS Bedrock access to all uses in account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-bedrock

We have AWS root account which has AWS Bedrock access, now we want to give access to all users in that account access to Bedrock.

When we login with non root user, it ask for `Sign up for preview`. We already signed up in root user and root user has `Getting Started` page.

How can we give access to all the user for Bedrock?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AWS Bedrock went into GA (general availability) last week. This means you do not need to sign up anymore. Delegating access to child account is possible via the usual means:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/bedrock/latest/userguide/model-access.html#manage-model-access

You can use this policy:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Statement1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "bedrock:*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, now I can see we can see all models.